# Is MySQL smart enough to not re-query for the max date for every item?

Tags: mysql

I've got a query which does a join like this:

```
LEFT JOIN history ON history.item_id=item.id AND history.date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM history WHERE item_id=item.id)
```

Is MySQL smart enough to execute the `SELECT MAX...` subquery only once?

---

**Edit:** Sorry, I should have mentioned the `WHERE` on the overall `SELECT` specifies a singular item id:

```
WHERE item.id=XXX
```

Comment: It'd cache the query, but since the subquery depends on values in the parent query, most likely you'd get a new MAX() scan each time, as the item_id will have changed for each subquery invocation.

Comment: @Marc: Oops... should have mentioned that the overall SELECT specifies an item_id, so it *isn't* different for each subquery. Actually.. wait. I think I screwed this whole question up. Point is, though, that the conditions would be the same for each row, otherwise this question wouldn't make sense. Can't cache it if the values were different.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer- NO.

Best practice is to use variables

```
SELECT @maxDate:= MAX(date) FROM history WHERE item_id=item.id
```

and then to use the variable @maxDate in your queries.

Comment: Might be off topic, but does PHP support this? If I execute this first in one `mysql_query` I can use that variable in a subsequent query? Actually, it doesn't even matter, because I could just use PHP variables instead...

Comment: @Mark Not into php that much.. but my guess would be that these variables have a life cycle of the connection... so as long as you do it in the same connection, you will be safe (probably)

Comment: @Mark: Yes, you can, but it has to be done via the same connection handle in PHP, as they're per-connection, not per-user.

Answer (score 2):

Do `explain plan` then the query and see

Im going to say No because this is a "correlated subquery"

see : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/07/sql-server-correlated-and-noncorrelated-subquery-introduction-explanation-and-example/

I know the DBMS in the blog is MSSQL but the same principle applies